# How can I display text above a button?

Tags: android

Only the button displays, but I want to see the text above the button

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/big_button_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:visibility="gone">
  <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/big_button"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/girrafffe"/>
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:text="Hello"
   android:layout_above="@id/big_button"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button_send"
  android:layout_width="150px"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="20dp"
  android:drawableBottom="@drawable/image"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:text="@string/send"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
```

`android:drawableBottom="@drawable/image"` will place the image of the button on the bottom thus allowing the text to be placed on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [TextView.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/big_button_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:visibility="gone">
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:text="Big Button"/>
  <ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/big_button"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/girrafffe"/>
  <TextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_above="@id/big_button"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

You may need to add some layouts to line everything up. However, this may work without them.

Comment: I am...what are you talking about?

Comment: well, your post changed several times, so probably he did not see your code at the moment he answered...

Comment: That is correct, you changed your post after i posted. I updated with more detail, since you provided more detail.